# Fetch unique records for multiple fields in elastic search version 6.2.3

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-6

I am new to elastic search. Using 6.2.3 version of elastic search.
I want elastic search equivalent of below SQL query:

**`SELECT  DISTINCT customer_name , customer_services, customer_visible from customers;`**

I have around 200K documents in elastic search. I want unique records for multiple fields from a document. Those fields are 
**customer_name ,
customer_services,
 customer_visible**

I am not looking for a count, I want to fetch data for specified fields with no duplicate data for each fields.

I have tried few queries , but it not giving me unique for all fields. 
Please help me in providing elastic search 6.2.3 equivalent query for above sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the working ES 6.3 equivalent query that worked for me.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "company_details": {
      "terms": {
        "size": 10000,
        "script": "doc['customer_global_cust_id'].value + ' | ' + doc['customer_name'].value + ' | ' + doc['customer_visible'].value + ' | ' +doc['customer_services'].values"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Above, I have used values for customer_services as it is array field in document, remaining field are just string value, hence value is used.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert, but as far as I know, if you wanted to do a select distinct on only one field, then you could have used [Term Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

But looking at this [Post](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/5100), Term aggregation on multiple fields is not supported in Elasticsearch, because it won't have good performance. You can look into the solution suggested in the same link about using `script` in term aggregation.

Comment: I have referred this post, tried scripted matrix but didn't work.